# What is apply plugin: 'java'

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

As said in the Gradle **[documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)**, section 6.4:

> Gradle's build scripts give you the full power of Groovy.

I come across the following command:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

I tried to googling to encquire what it means at the Groovy point of view, but I have no idea. Is there a Groovy equivalent at all?

Comment: It imports the Java plugin for gradle, including a lot of predefined commands/tasks. This might be useful: http://www.gradle.org/plugins

Comment: Since you are aware of userguide documentation you can take a look at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/plugins.html If that's not enough you can look for Groovy DSL to see various ways how to implement your own domain specific language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you see is a syntactic sugar provided by Groovy for a method call. [No braces in method calls & implicit map coercion]

`apply plugin: 'java'` is same as `apply([plugin: 'java'])`

[`apply()`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#apply(java.util.Map)) is available in Gradle's Project API and `project` instance is available in Gradle build script by default. (In Groovy terms, operations in `build.gradle` is delegated to `project`)