# What is the compile group, name etc...?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I come across the following method invocation:

```
dependencies {
   compile group: 'commons-collections', name : 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
}
```

Well, `dependencies(Closure closure)`'s defined in [Project](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) and the code above is just its invocation.

But what is the closure's body in the Groovy point of view?

```
compile group: 'commons-collections', name : 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From groovy point of view this statement:

`compile group: 'commons-collections', name : 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'`

is just a normal `Map`. It works exactly the same as in:

`apply plugin: 'java'` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366653/what-is-apply-plugin-java/26366836#26366836) for details.

Comment: You mean we have three method invokations in the closure's body which takes Map as argumets, right?

Comment: But as far as I understand this method is not a method defined in Project. Why can we call it?

Comment: You don't invoke it on `project` instance but on configuration instance - in this particular case `compile` configuration. And You don't invoke a method three times but pass a `Map` with three keys.

Comment: Nope you have one method call as `compile([group: 'abc', name: 'foo', version: '3.2'])`. @St.Antario

Comment: @Opal What is it? We can invoke that method since we apply Java plugin. Does `apply plugin 'java'` add additional methods we can invoke as a method of Project?

Comment: Technically, `compile group: 'commons-collections', name : 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'` is a call to a *dynamic* `DependencyHandler#compile` method that takes three named parameters (which Groovy turns into a map). Such a method exists because the `java` plugin has declared a configuration (think "dependency scope") named `compile`.

Comment: With `apply` it's a bit easier because here You can find the method declaration that takes a `Map` as an argument: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#apply(groovy.lang.Closure). With configurations it's a bit different because they're created at runtime.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser You talk about that http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html configuration, right?

Comment: @St.Antario Yes. The dynamic method effectively delegates to `DependencyHandler.add('compile', group: 'commons-collections', name : 'commons-collections', version: '3.2')`.

Comment: @Opal That's if I define my own `Configuration` object and add method say `myMethod(Closure closure)` to it I can call it in a build script just as `myMethod{ //... }`. Could you provide a simple example to understand it?

Comment: This isn't a general mechanism but implemented by `DependencyHandler`. If you are referring to the fact that a closure can have a dynamic scope, that's a Groovy feature called "closure delegate". For example, inside a `dependencies {}` block you can call methods on `DependencyHandler` without qualification (because the `Project#dependencies` method sets it up this way).

Comment: @St.Antario, as Peter mentioned, this is how it works and is implemented. What a discussion :)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#dependencies%28groovy.lang.Closure%29):

> ```
> void dependencies(Closure configureClosure)
> ```
>
> Configures the dependencies for this project.
>
> This method executes the given closure against the DependencyHandler for this project. The DependencyHandler is passed to the closure as the closure's delegate.

So basically this is a `DependencyHandler` instance and `compile([group: ...])` is called upon